# Potential yields of Np-237 using a synchotron

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons, gamma-rays, particle-accelerators, isotopes

U238 releases a neutron when it is exposed to photons of around 11 MeV, and the resulting U237 promptly decays into the fissile Np237.

In such a situation, what equations can I use to relate the quantum flux of a hypothetical synchrotron which will produce the gamma rays, and the amount of Np237 generated as a function of time?

Comment: Is the cross section of the (gamma,neutron) reaction not sufficient? Although it is not directly found at ENDF.

Comment: A measurement from 8-22MeV is available at Physical Review: https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.89.1042 showing a peak in the cross section at about 10MeV. It is only 0.5 barns, so not super large. Other papers can be found into the GeV range.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you!